# iframe with main domain and sub-domain

Tags: iframe-resizer

I have tried the various methods mentioned here to get the iframe to change height. It works on the initial load with the original src domain, but when the link to the sub-domain s clicked inside the iframe I get the following error:

`Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('https://www.profiledata.co.za') does not match the recipient window's origin ('https://funds.profiledata.co.za').`

URL: https://www.iol.co.za/business-report/market-indicators
Click on Funds to get the sub-domain.

I have tried checkOrigin as false as well as an array with both domains in it, and I still get the same error. It does not resize the iframe on the sub-domain page(s). Any ideas, thanks.

Comment: The Same Origin Policy prohibits different sub-domains, but there is a way to bypass that restriction using [document.domain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy#Changing_origin). As for that url with the entirely different host:`iol.co.za` , what is that? It looks totally sketchy.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding heightCalculationMethod: 'bodyScroll' in the option. or try changing the value of this option. you can see all the value for heightCalculationMethod in http://davidjbradshaw.github.io/iframe-resizer/

```
iFrameResize({log:true,
  autoResize:true,
  checkOrigin:false,
  interval:32,
  heightCalculationMethod: 'bodyScroll'
});
```